# Como aplicar un patch completo en intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

He tenido algunos inconvenientes al aplicar un `.patch` en Intellij, al inicio todo funciona bien pero después de continuar me muestra una ventana diciéndome que algunos cambios no pudieron aplicarse y debo de aplicarlos de manera manual, en lugar de aplicar todos los cambios sin mostrar esa ventana o excepción. ¿Algo hice mal o tengo que configurar algo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, no hiciste nada mal. Lo que sucede es que estás teniendo un conflicto porque la revisión sobre la que crearon el parche no es la misma versión sobre la que tu estás por lo que algunas de las secciones que indica el parche ya no se corresponden con tu código actual. Puedes mirar cuales son los hunks que fallaron y aplicarlos manualmente.... también podrías considerar ir a la revisión exacta sobre la que se creó el parche para que lo puedas aplicar sin problemas. Si estás usando git (y es un parche de git, creado con `git format-patch`, por ejemplo), podrías intentar usar `git apply --3way`.

Comment: El parche es de gitlab, ¿funcionaria igual que Github?

Comment: Ni idea.... los dos proveedores trabajan con git así que supongo que es aplicable. Abre el archivo y miras las primeras líneas. Si tiene un encabezado donde dice el autor, la hora a la que se hizo la revision que está en el parche, un comentario y luego tiene los diffs entonces es un parche de una revisión de git y se podría hacer  lo que digo de correr `git apply --3way`.

Comment: Sí, si es un parche de una revisión de git. Gracias amigo, para la próxima utilizaré esa alternativa.